# How do I prove that if $f$ is continuous, then $F_{0}'(x) = f(x)$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

If $f$ is continuous on the interval $I = [a,b]$, then $f$ has an antiderivative on $I$.

Define a function $F_0(x) = \int_a^x f$ for $a \le x \le b$

If $x$ and $x+h$ both lie in $I$, then

$F_{0}(x+h) -F_{0}(x) = \int_a^{x+h} f - \int_a^x f$

= $\int_x^{x+h} f = f(\bar{x})h$

where we use the mean value theorem for integrals and $\bar{x}$ lies between $x$ and $x+h$. divide by $h$, and let $h$ approach $0$; since $\bar{x}$ must then approach $x$, and since $f$ is continuous, we find $F'_{0}(x) = f(x)$, and $F_{0}$ is an antiderivative of $f$. (When $x$ is an endpoint of $I$, the argument shows the appropriate one-sided derivative of $F_{0}$ has the correct value.)

Looking at the part that says that "since $f$ is continuous, we find $F'_{0}(x) = f(x)$." I wanted to know if there's a way to show more precisely that if $f$ is continuous, then $F_{0}'(x) = f(x)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following your argument, you have that $$\frac{F_0(x_0+h)-F_0(x_0)}{h}=f(\bar x),$$ but the mean value theorem aserts that $\bar x\in[x_0,x_0+h]$ (or viceversa if $h<0$). So, in fact, $\bar x$ depends on $h$.

So if $h\to0$, then the interval $[x_0,x_0+h]$ goes to the singleton ${x_0}$, and $\bar x\to x_0$ as $h\to 0$. So, if you put all together, you'll have $$F_0'(x_0)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{F_0(x_0+h)-F_0(x_0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}f(\bar x)= f(x_0),$$ where the last equality holds because of the continuity of $f$.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is continuous at $x$ then, for any $\varepsilon > 0$ there is an $1 \geq r > 0$ such that the relation $|h| < r$ implies $|f(x+h)-f(x)|<\varepsilon.$ By noticing, $F_0(x+h)-F_0(x)=\int\limits_x^{x+h}(f-f(x))+f(x)h$ we reach at once $\left| \dfrac{F_0(x+h)-F_0(x) - f(x)}{h}\right| \leq \varepsilon |h| \leq \varepsilon.$ (The same proof applies whatever the normed space $F$ and $f$ were defined.) Q.E.D

Comment: where does the $(f -f(x)) + f(x)h$ come from?

Comment: Addition of numbers: $f(t) = f(t) - f(x) + f(x).$